# Trouble with displaying a variable at a interval in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code:

```
function displayWelcome() {
    console.log("Welcome! \nThis program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.")
}

function calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate) {
    return Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
}

function displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {

    console.log("Balance on your credit card: $" + balance.toFixed(2))
    console.log("Interest Rate: " + (interest * 100) + "%")
    console.log("Assuming a minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)")
    console.log("Your minimum payment would be: $" + minimumPayment)
    console.log("\nYear    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid")

    var year = 1;
    var payments = 1;
    var interestPaid = 0;

    while (balance > 0) {

        interestPaid += balance * interest / 12;

        balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));

        console.log(year + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) + "      " + payments + "              " + interestPaid.toFixed(2));
        year++;
        payments++;
    }
}

var balance = 1500;
var minimumPaymentRate = 0.02;
var interest = 0.18;

displayWelcome()
var minimumPayment = calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate);

displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment);
```

Now the problem with this is that the output displays correctly except the year count. The year should only be repeating every 12 payments but for some reason, it keeps repeating every payment. I have tried modifying the loop but to no avail. This is the output I get:

```
Year    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid
    1       1492.50     1             22.50
    2       1484.89     2             44.89
    3       1477.16     3             67.16
    4       1469.32     4             89.32
    5       1461.36     5             111.36
    6       1453.28     6             133.28
    7       1445.08     7             155.08
    8       1436.75     8             176.75
    9       1428.31     9             198.31
    10      1419.73     10            219.73
    11      1411.03     11            241.03
    12      1402.19     12            262.19
```

Desired output:

```
Year    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid
    1       1492.50     1             22.50
            1484.89     2             44.89
            1477.16     3             67.16
            1469.32     4             89.32
            1461.36     5             111.36
            1453.28     6             133.28
            1445.08     7             155.08
            1436.75     8             176.75
            1428.31     9             198.31
            1419.73     10            219.73
            1411.03     11            241.03
    2       1402.19     12            262.19
```

Comment: You do `year++` every time through the loop, why shouldn't it increment on every line? Change the code so you only increment `year` when `payments` is a multiple of 12.

Comment: Your desired output shows 11 payments per year - is this correct? Or should it be 12 payments per year (1 per month)?

Comment: @JamesMonger that was a mistake, meant to have it on the 13 payment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It keeps repeating because of this loop

```
while (balance > 0) {

    interestPaid += balance * interest / 12;

    balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));

    console.log(year + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) + "      " + payments + "              " + interestPaid.toFixed(2));
    year++;
    payments++;
}
```

You increase **year** and display it every time the loop executes.

To fix that, change the incrementation to:

```
if(payments % 12 == 0) // If multiple of 12 (aka: a year)
    year++;
```

To format it how you want (only show year when it changes) you can try to add a flag like so:

```
var year = 1;
var payments = 1;
var interestPaid = 0
var yearChanged;


while (balance > 0) {
    yearChanged = false; // Automatically set the flag to false

    if(payments % 12 == 0) {
        year++;
        yearChanged = true; // Change it when year change
    }

        interestPaid += balance * interest / 12;

        balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));

                    // if flag = true show year
        console.log(yearChanged ? year : "-" + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) + "      " + payments + "              " + interestPaid.toFixed(2));

        payments++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of increasing `year` variable - if it's connected to the `payments` - so 1-12 is first year, 13-24 - second year, ... you can simplify it to:

```
var year = Math.ceil(payments / 12);
console.log(year + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) + "      " + payments + "              " + interestPaid.toFixed(2));
```